# Specify Room Type in Twilio Video iOS SDK

Tags: twilio

How do I specify the room type in iOS? This is how I connect to a room, [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios-v3-getting-started#connect-to-a-room).

Just wondering if room type can only be specified if room is first created using [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-list-resource).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to use the Twilio WebRTC Go, I'm following this link: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-ios and https://www.twilio.com/blog/announcing-twilio-video-webrtc-go. But the room type is set to group even after making changes to room settings in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only create a room and set its type by the REST API. The resources for group rooms are set up on the server side, which is why you need to create the room via the API.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I searched https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios but couldn't find any sample code that uses REST API. Do you mind sharing code on your github page?

Comment: You already linked to [the sample code for using the REST API to create rooms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-list-resource) in your question. You will need to do that from a server and not from your iOS application as it requires using your account sid and auth token which should not be exposed to the client side.

Comment: Hey @philnash I want to set up Twilio WebRTC Go in my ios app for one to one video calling, but am not able to find where to start. There are so many docs scattered all over. Could you please guide me how can I add the functionality to my app?

Comment: @Arjun WebRTC Go is just a special kind of room that only allows 1:1, peer to peer connections. So all the documentation is applicable and the SDK is the same as any other Twilio Video usage. For iOS [start here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios) and check out both the [quickstart app and examples](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios) as well as the [fully featured example app](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-ios).

Comment: Hello @philnash. Thanks for your reply, I've started with the fully featured example app that you've mentioned above, but am unable to set the room type to Go, I also posted the question on SO, could you please help me with this? Here's the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728394/twilio-room-type-not-set-to-go-even-after-changing-room-settings-in-console

Comment: @Arjun Answered your question.