# Twilio room type not set to GO even after changing room settings in console

Tags: twilio, twilio-video, webrtc-ios

I'm following the links below to setup Twilio WebRTC Go - one to one video calling app on iOS using Swift

https://www.twilio.com/blog/announcing-twilio-video-webrtc-go
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-ios

But when I run the app and generate the Access Token using

```
twilio rtc:apps:video:deploy --authentication passcode
```

I'm getting the room type as

```
Room Type: group
```

I've set the room type to Go in the console in room settings, even then it returns "group".

How do I change the room type to GO? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your token server determines the room type and [you can set the room type when you deploy the server using the `--room-type` flag](https://github.com/twilio-labs/plugin-rtc#twilio-rtcappsvideodeploy---authentication-auth).

```
twilio rtc:apps:video:deploy --authentication passcode --room-type go
```

So, redeploy your token server, pass `--room-type go` and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you @philnash. I've set the room type to Go

Comment: Regarding the Go room, in the video calling app, can the same room name be used between two users every time they call or should the room name be different for every call? Like which is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can re-use room names, you just need to ensure that when you're using Go rooms that you don't use the same room name for more than one pair of users as only 2 participants will ever be able to join at the same time. If you create a room name using identifiers for each of your users, like `"${userA.id}-${userB.id}"`, then that will work nicely as a permanent room name that can be safely used without other users barging in on them.

Comment: Yes that is definitely a solid solution.

Comment: I'm able to run the fully featured example here, https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-ios How do I go about adding these features and code to my app? Should I straight away move all folders to my app and set it up or how should I go about it? I have already built an app using swift where there are users with unique ID and they could chat with each other, I want to add a call button in chat which when they press starts the WebRTC Go call with room name as you suggested

Comment: I would recommend building the application into yours from scratch, taking inspiration and example code from the example app. I would imagine it would be easier to build it as part of your application, rather than trying to mash two apps together, plus building the parts out yourself will mean you understand all the parts of the application, which will make debugging easier.

Comment: Totally, this is a great recommendation. I'll dive straight into adding the video calling to my app. Really appreciate your help :D

Comment: Hello, I've implemented the twilio webrtc GO app inside my app. I wanted to integrate it with CallKit. Like when userA joins the room, a notification is sent to userB and it shows the CallKit UI, basically receiving the call and when he accepts the call, he joins the room. Where should I start to achieve this feature? I can send notification using Firebase Cloud Function and am successfully able to send them. Your help would really be appreciated